# Inject multiple content scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a couple of extensions which use multiple content scripts. Adding these via the manifest means they aren't available when the extension is first installed (user must refresh content pages first), so the extension appears not to work, and users un-install it!

Have tried a number of things but can't find a way of injecting multiple javascript files. Has anyone found a way of doing this, or alerting the user to the fact pages need to be refreshed before the extension can be run?

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to reload tabs with `chrome.tabs.reload` when your extension is installed ? 
  http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-reload

Comment: Haven't found a work-a-round yet, but have added an alert so the user knows whats happening...  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {  
  linkAudit.log('alert if not loaded');  
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:'if(!window.linkAudit){alert("Please reload the page to run Link Audit")}'})  
 });

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to refresh pages, use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` for injecting to all old pages.

Check the working version of sample implementation.

## Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Registered Background Page and given all permissions to Chrome Extension.

```
{
    "name": "Inject Code",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727263/inject-multiple-content-scripts",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

#### background.js

Inject code using query API

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    //Fetch all inactive completly loaded tabs or use your own query
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: false,
        "status": "complete"
    }, function (tabs) {
        for (tab in tabs) { //It returns array of tabs
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[tab].id, {
                "file": "inject.js" //Inject Code
            });
        }
    });
});
```

#### inject.js

```
console.log("Injected..");
```

## Output

You would see script injected without need for refresh of Page.

## References

- [Tab API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You con use dynamical script injection please [see](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)